# code for make a entry for each radio button list into database

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a 14 radio button list each denoted facility for college i.e classroom,labs,and sport facility etc.,i need a code which help me to insert a separate data for each radio button list.a database having 2 column first column contain facility and second column contain ranks i.e excellent,very good ,good and average for each facility.

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">1.Classrooms</label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbclassrooms" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">2.Laboratories </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="dblab" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">3.Central Library </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbcentrallib" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">4. Cleanliness  </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbclean" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">5. Central Computing Center </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbccc" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">6. Wi-Fi Facility </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbwifi" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">7. Hostel Facilities </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbhostel" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">8. Sport Facility </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbsport" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">9. College Bus Transport </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbcolgbus" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">10. Canteen Facility</label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbcanteen" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">11. ATM Facility </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbatm" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">12.    Counseling and Health Care  </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbcounselingandhealth" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">13.    Washroom and drinking water </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbwashroom" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label style="font-size: large">14.    Overall Facilities  </label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rboverall" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Excellent
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Very Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Good
            <asp:ListItem style="margin-right:50px">Average

           </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: what if 4 different queries (one for each facility/avg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options

1) Keep on connection open and execute multiple insert statements likes

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmdClassroom= new SqlCommand("insert into YourTable(Facility,Rank)Values(@facility,@rank)", connection))
    {
       cmdClassroom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@facility,"Classroom");
       cmdClassroom.Parameters.AddWithValue(@rank,rbclassrooms.SelectedValue);
    }
//Similarly for next facilities
    using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandText2, connection))
    {
    }
    // etc
}
```

2) put semicolon on each query

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
command.CommandText = @"
 insert into YourTable (facility,rank) values ('classroom',@classroomRank);
 insert into YourTable (facility,rank) values ('labs',@labsRank);
 insert into YourTable (facility,rank) values ('lib',@libRank);
 insert into YourTable (facility,rank) values ('Cleanliness',@cleanlinessRank);

 command.Connection = connection;
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Hope this helps!